Enabling Chrome Flag for System Audio Recording in Electron App for mac
I'm currently working on a desktop application for recording, and I've hit a bit of a roadblock. Specifically, I'm trying to record system audio, and I found that Chrome has a flag #mac-loopback-audio-for-screen-share that seems to enable this.
I've been trying to enable this flag within our Electron app, but so far, no luck. I followed the standard procedure as per the documentation, but it doesn’t seem to work.
My questions are:
Is it possible to enable Chrome flags like #mac-loopback-audio-for-screen-share within an Electron app?
Am I missing something in the process?
Are there certain flags that Electron doesn't support, and if so, is there a list or a way to know which ones are supported?
Thanks
We have tried

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-mac-system-audio-loopback');


Note: There's an open Chromium issue which describes that flag as expired: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/355308245

They are going to enable this flag by default, meaning it will be directly usable with Electron. As a result, the question will no longer be relevant and can be removed.
